# MySQL select specific entry from a table which is not in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a problem in MySQL when trying to select specific entry from table which is not in another table. I know this sentence sounds nuts but here is an example what I am trying to do.

Table users:

```
    user_id,username,password (plus other columns not important to this)
```

Table articles:

```
    article_is,user_id,content (plus others)
```

Table views (used to store data if user viewed specific article):

```
   view_id,article_id,user_id,date
```

Now, I am trying to select those users who has NOT read a specific article, for example article with id 10. So they have no entry in the views table.

I hope it makes more sense now.
Thanks for your answers. V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id FROM users u
LEFT JOIN views v ON v.user_id=u.user_id AND v.article_id = 10
WHERE v.user_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM users
WHERE user_id NOT IN (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM views
  WHERE article_id = 10
)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.. it works however I will stick with the below answers because of the performance :)

Comment: Before you decide which version to choose, test (performance).

Comment: huh, finding out, there are not that much differences in performance,.. too bad i cant flag more answers as correct :/

Comment: @ypercube I have only small amount of entries I can try it on.. the overall time is the same for both methods there differences in time of individual steps .. which method is better in your opinion?

Comment: See the link in my comment in DRapp's answer.

Comment: interesting .. the differences can be seen by the naked eye when dealing with larger sum of values ..

Answer (score 3):

doing NOT IN queries are not typically great for performance... instead, using LEFT JOIN and looking for NULL would be better.

```
select 
      u.User_ID
   from 
      Users U
         LEFT JOIN Views V
            on U.User_ID = V.User_ID 
           AND v.Article_ID = 10
   where
      V.User_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Performance difference: not true, according to @Quassnoi. See: [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: thank you for the answer, vearutop however posted an answer a little quicker and i will grant him the correct answer .. thank you again!

Comment: @Vojtech, I can respect that... however just posting a query without explanation... does that really help you understand WHY something works?  I try to describe the WHY behind doing certain approach to querying.