# MySQL: Select entries that do not exist in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table called quotesArtists which lists all celebs that we currently have quotes for.

I have another table called celebs that has the profiles of all celebs.

I want to list all entries in my celebs table that currently do NOT have quotes. How do i do that? Tks!

Comment: By reading a basic sql tutorial. Hint: left join.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because no effort at all is shown and the question can be answered by any tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `left join`

```
select c.*
from celebs c
left join quotesArtists q on q.celecb_id = c.id
where q.celeb_id is null
```

See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Everything for the rep, isn't it?

Comment: [should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/210840/)

Comment: Yes, may I quote your post? "One user who hasn't tried anything is a tad annoying. 10,000 users who haven't tried anything is, more or less, the death of the site." and "Lack of research effort leading to countless duplicates". That's where you're leading SO to by answering such questions. And SQL is quite established, don't you think? Not some badly documented new thing.

Comment: *And just as there are annoying, time-wasting teachers who demand to see long division next to the solutions to algebra problems, there are annoying people who demand to see "what you've tried" for questions where the only sane answer is "nothing, because I don't know what to try*

Comment: I'd agree to your point for programming questions or more complex sql queries, but we're talking here about one of the basics of sql. And the question itself is actually okay, as long as it's not already answered. But this kind of question gets asked here daily. So my point is, that those questions are either not answered or the better alternative, which I should've done in the first place, close as duplicate (picked from the "related" column to the right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912230/mysql-select-specific-entry-from-a-table-which-is-not-in-another-table?rq=1).

Comment: I have tried searching for the answers but i couldn't find the right question to search and thus couldn't find that the answer lied with joins. I'm not a programmer so i've no idea about joins until now. I do understand the point about repeat questions, but don't be too quick to judge someone just because you know alot. And you can see that i created this account just to ask this question when i have been using this site for answers alot longer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.*
from celebs c
left join quotesArtists q on q.celecb_id = c.id
where q.celeb_id is null
```

OR

```
select c.*
from celebs c
WHERE c.id NOT IN (select celecb_id from quotesArtists)
```